# What are some topos-theoretic insights about $G$-sets?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-actions, topos-theory

Since a $G$-set is just a functor $G\longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$, the category of $G$-sets seems to be a simple example of a topos.

What are some topos-theoretic insights into $G$-sets? Insights deserving to be called "geometric" are particularly welcome (hopefully with an explanation).

Comment: This is the topos-theoretic version of the classifying space $B G$, also called the Eilenberg–MacLane space $K (G, 1)$.

Comment: To amplify Zhen Lin's comment, geometric morphisms from any topos $E$ to $G$-sets are equivalent to torsors under $G$ in $E$ (where $G$ actually means $p^*(G)$ for the geometric morphism $p:E\to$ Sets).

Comment: Also, for any homomorphism $f:G\to H$ of groups, there is an induced geometric morphism from $G$-sets to $H$-sets.  Its inverse-image part also has a left adjoint, which is a permutation-action version of induced representations.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I am ignorant of everything you have said. Could you recommend some references to learn these things, including this particular example of $G$-sets?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I learned this sort of thing from Johnstone's book, "Topos Theory". I don't think there's much there specifically about $G$-sets, but there's a lot about  presheaf topoi, and it's a good exercise to read that with the special case of $G$-sets foremost in your mind. The left adjoint that I mentioned explicitly and the right adjoint that's implicit in a geometric morphism are right and left Kan extensions, and these are treated in Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician."

Comment: Another book that you might find useful is "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic" by Mac Lane and Moerdijk.  I'm not very familiar with it, because it appeared after I had already learned most of this material, but I've heard good things about it from others; in particular, it might be easier to read than Johnstone's book.